# pandas read_html, why is it saying NaN when there is data in the row

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to scrape [this](http://isyslab.info/NeuroPep/search_info?pepNum=NP00001) page.

I wrote this code:

```
import pandas as pd
output_file = open('neuropep.txt', 'a')
for i in range(1,2):
       number = '{:05}'.format(i)
       url = 'http://isyslab.info/NeuroPep/search_info?pepNum=NP' + str(number)
       tables = pd.read_html(url)
       print(tables[0][1])
```

The output from this is:

```
0                           NP00001
1     7B2 C-terminal peptide (5-13)
2                 Rattus norvegicus
3                             10116
4                               NaN
5                               7B2
6                               NaN
7                                 9
8                               NaN
9                               NaN
10                        FSEEEKEPE
11                             View
12                              NaN
13                              NaN
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

But I can see from the link, that row 13 should say:

```
Karlsson O, Kultima K, Wadensten H, Nilsson A, Roman E, Andrén PE, Brittebo EB Neurotoxin-induced neuropeptide perturbations in striatum of neonatal rats J Proteome Res 2013 Apr 5;12(4):1678-90
PMID: 23410195
```

I can't work out the discrepancy? I tried to mess with printing different parts of the tables, but I'm not sure how to work out where the missing data is. I don't actually need the whole reference, just the PubMed ID.

Edit 1: tried with beautifulsoup:

```
for i in range(1,2):
                number = '{:05}'.format(i)
                url = 'http://isyslab.info/NeuroPep/search_info?pepNum=NP' + str(number)
                res = requests.get(url)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')
                table = soup.find_all('li')
                print(table)
```

Comment: my guess is read_html is unable to read the li tags, go for 'request' and 'beautifulsoup' you'll have more control

Comment: I appreciate the comment, I tried the script with bs4 and requests above, but i don't think the pmid is in a li (or in a table), when i do 'table = soup.find_all()', I can see it '        var reference = String('23410195#Karlsson O, Kultima K, Wadensten H, Nilsson A, Roman E, Andrén PE, Brittebo EB#Neurotoxin-induced neuropeptide perturbations in striatum of neonatal rats#J Proteome Res 2013 Apr 5;12(4):1678-90 ');' ;so I'm just wondering, what is X in this expression: 'table = soup.findall(X)' to make it see the reference.